# Mixed stack IOS upgrade - Cisco 3750x,3750G

Tags: switch, cisco-ios, cisco-3750

I have a mixed switch stack : -

```
Switch Ports Model              SW Version            SW Image                 
------ ----- -----              ----------            ----------               
*    1 52    WS-C3750G-48PS     12.2(55)SE            C3750-IPBASEK9-M         
     2 54    WS-C3750X-48P      12.2(55)SE            C3750E-UNIVERSALK9-M     
     5 54    WS-C3750X-48P      12.2(55)SE            C3750E-UNIVERSALK9-M
```

Now, I am required to upgrade the stack to SE10 versions of the IOS code.

Steps that I will be taking:-

1. Copy SE10 version of IPBASE on switch 1
2. Copy SE10 version of UNIVERSAL9 on switch2,5.
3. Change boot statements to the respective IOS files.
4. Reload the stack.

Questions/Concerns:-

1. Is this the best method to go for this task?
2. Will this cause mismatch between the switch and cause the stack to
   break?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is correct, and assuming you get the same version number for all of them, you should be fine.  If you're connected to the stack master, a "dir" should show flash file systems matching each switch (flash-1:, flash-2:, flash-5:).

Remember these when you're copying the files over, but I don't *think* you'll need them when you go to configure your boot statement - you should be able to just say "boot system switch 1 flash:", "boot system switch 2 flash:," etc.

The flash on those switches should be big enough to hold a second copy of IOS.  I'd recommend retaining your current version of IOS in addition to the new version to make roll-back easy.